# Quick Exponential Growth Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So I was given the following prompt:

"Suppose it takes $125$ seconds for a certain bacteria culture to grow from a population of $150$ organisms to $160$ organisms. How many hours will it take for the bacteria culture to grow from $150$ organisms to a population of $1,000,000$ organisms?"

I thought I knew how to tackle something like this. I used the equation: $y=ce^{kt}$ and I substituted the given initial amounts and time interval into this equation (which ended up looking something like this: $160=150e^{125k}$) so that I could find my $k$ value, which ended up being really small, somewhere around $0.000516$. I then plugged this value back into the same equation ($1000000=150e^{0.000516t}$), but I ended up getting a really, really big answer that I have no clue if it's right or not ($17,053$). I guess I'm looking for whether or not I made some sort of an error in my process and whether or not this answer is right. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Remember that the units are in seconds, so that's really $17053$ seconds, i.e. about $4.7$ hours, so not actually all that long.